# Implementing SUR on weighted regression models

Tags: weighted-regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions, simultaneous-equation

I have two equations:

```r
fit1= svyglm(Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3, design= design.mnps, data= data) 

fit2= svyglm(Y2 ~ X1 + X2 + X3, design= design.mnps, data= data)
```

`Y1` and `Y2` (both continuous variables) are highly correlated. Questions:

1. Should I use the Seemingly Unrelated Regression model or treat them independently, or use any other model?
2. Is there any resource that explains the implementation of SUR (or similar models) for weighted regressions? I use R.

Comment: 1. SUR won't do you any good if all the right-hand side variables in the two equations are the same. 2. It's not surprising that the target variables are correlated, given that they are functions of the same right-hand side variables.  That's OK.  The real SUR question is, are the *residuals* of the two equations correlated?

Comment: Yes, the residuals of the two equations are also correlated (~0.8).

Answer (score 0):

If the two outcome variables are measured on the same units the procedure is  reasonably straightforward, though I don't think there's an existing implementation.

1. Use sampling-weighted least squares (eg with `svyglm`) on each equation
2. Estimate the population $2\times 2$ covariance matrix of residuals (eg with `svyvar`)
3. Fit a sampling-weighted GLS estimate with the estimated covariance matrix. This step isn't implemented; it could probably be done with `withReplicates` and `nlme::gls` or with `svymle`

As @jbowman says, there's no actual point in doing this if you have the same regressors in both models. But if you have an example where it would make a difference, you might try writing to the `survey` package maintainer. Even better if you had a published example to work with.

**Update**:  If you don't have stratified sampling (or you're prepared to ignore it) you could also use GEE with an 'unstructured' working correlation matrix (which is the same as the IGLS algorithm for SUR). Stack the two models, and make sure the two `observations` for each unit are in the same cluster.